# Need a regex that can solve the below mentioned condition

Tags: regex, preg-match, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Need regex for validating

condition 1
If first digit is 0-7 then max length will be 10 digit and space after 6 digit
Example: 102345 6789

condition 2
If first digit is 9 then max length will be 11 digit and space after 7 digit
Example: 9123456 1234

condition 3
If first digit is 8 then second digit will be 2 , max length will be 11 and space after 7 digit
Example: 8212345 1234

Comment: `([0-7]\d{5}|9\d{6}|82\d{5}) \d{4}` ?

Comment: (?=^[0-7])[0-9]{10}$|(?=^[8]2[2])[0-9]{11}$|(?=^[9])[0-9]{11}$ Have tried this working for me but having issue with the space

Comment: Not working for me @kishkin

Comment: [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3iyIc6/1). Can you provide some context for what you are trying to achieve? Also a few match and no-match examples.

Comment: When you say "max length" does this include that first digits?

Comment: Yes max length includes 1st digit

Comment: included the example in the question

Comment: What is not working for the pattern I gave first? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3iyIc6/4) (with new examples)

Comment: Thanks the demo one is working i have tested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?:[0-7]\d{5}|9\d{6}|82\d{5}) \d{4}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3iyIc6/4)

Answer (score 1):

use `\b(?:[0-7]|82|9\d)\d{5} \d{4}\b`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/3tiN6Y/1)